# Proving $\text{vol}(A) \le \sum_{i=1}^N \text{vol}(A_i)$ where $A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that
$\displaystyle\text {vol}(A) \le \sum_{i=1}^N \text {vol}(A_i)$ where $\displaystyle A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i$. This is intuitively very clear but I cannot think of another way to prove it other than saying
$$
\text {vol}(A) = \int_A \chi_A \le \text {vol}(B) = \int_B \chi_B \le \sum_{i = 1}^N \text {vol}(A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^N \int_{A_i} \chi_{A_i}
$$
where $B = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_N$. Does what I wrote down here complete the proof? Are there better ways of showing what I am trying to prove here? Thanks!

Comment: You just need a little more ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\chi_{A_1\cup A_2} = \chi_{A_1}+ \chi_{A_2}- \chi_{A_1\cap A_2}\leqslant \chi_{A_1}+ \chi_{A_2}$$

By an easy inductive argument,

$$\chi_{\cup_{j=1}^NA_j} = \chi_{\cup_{j=1}^{N-1}A_j\cup A_N}\leqslant  \chi_{\cup_{j=1}^{N-1}A_j}+ \chi_{A_N} \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^N \chi_{A_j}$$

By monotonicity and **additivity** of the integral with ambient space $X$,

$$\int_X\chi_{\cup_{j=1}^NA_j}\leqslant \int_X \sum_{j=1}^N \chi_{A_j} = \sum_{j=1}^N \int_X\chi_{A_j}$$

Since $A \subset \cup_{j=1}^NA_j$, we have $\chi_A \leqslant \chi_{\cup_{j=1}^NA_j}$, and

$$vol(A) = \int_X \chi_A \leqslant \int_X\chi_{\cup_{j=1}^NA_j}\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^N \int_X\chi_{A_j} = \sum_{j=1}^N vol(A_j)$$

Comment: This is much clearer proof than what I have. Thank you very much!

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics: You're welcome.